# How to populate listview according to database in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am having a class to get all MessageThread as:

```
public List<ChatMessageThread> getAllMessageThread() {

        List<ChatMessageThread> chatMessageThreads = new ArrayList<ChatMessageThread>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ChatMessageThread;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ChatMessageThread td = new ChatMessageThread();
                td.setChatMessageThreadId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ChatMessageThreadId))));
                td.setMessageThreadTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MessageThreadTitle))));
                td.setMessageThreadURL(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MessageThreadURL)));
                td.setMessageThreadSnippet(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MessageThreadSnippet)));

                // Adding contact to list
                chatMessageThreads.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return chatMessageThreads;
    }
```

how can i populate this list in listview of my ListView in Layout file

Comment: make this list as source for your adapter for listview. Done

Answer (score 0):

i use this method:

```
private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<ChatMessageThread> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        list.setAdapter(null);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

also the the MyListAdapter method:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatMessageThread> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listitem, ChatMessageThreadObject);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listitem,
                        parent, false);
            }

            // Find the object to work with
            ChatMessageThread working_object = ChatMessageThreadObject.get(position);

            // set a textview from the listitem layout
            TextView startTime = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.t_v_startTime);
            startTime.setText(working_object.getID());
            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

p.s. i edited my objects to refer to your answer. i hope this helps you :)

Comment: private ArrayList<ChatMessageThread> ChatMessageThreadObject=getAllMessageThread();